# What alphanumerical ordering scheme does SAS PROC FORMAT follow?

Tags: sas, alphanumeric

I have provided a contrived example, based on content of http://support.sas.com/kb/33/017.html

What ordering standard or system does SAS use to determine the order of the `PROC FREQ` at the end of this code block?

```
 proc format lib=work;
    value $productfmt
           "Boot"           = "<"
           "Men's Casual"   = "!"
           "Women's Casual" = "A" 
           "Men's Dress"    = "B" 
           "Women's Dress"  = "5"
           "Sandal"         = "6" 
           "Slipper"        = "7" 
           "Sport Shoe"     = "08" ;    
QUIT;

data work.newshoes;
 set sashelp.shoes; /* the original data set */
     NEWPRODUCT = PRODUCT;

    format NEWPRODUCT $productfmt.;
run;

proc freq data=work.newshoes order=formatted;
    table NEWPRODUCT;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with normal SAS character sorting or comparisons, it is looking at the underlying numeric codes that define the character.  On Windows or Unix, that's the ASCII code (on some other systems, EBCDIC).  Generally, you have the numbers smaller than the letters, and upper case smaller than lower case.  Most of the other characters you can type on a standard English keyboard will be found before the letters, either before or after the numbers (the comparison operators and a few others are after the numbers, the characters that are printed on top of the numbers are before the numbers except for @, but otherwise it seems random to me).  See [an ASCII table](http://ascii.cl/) for more information.

You can see the first ASCII value in a string using `RANK` (and if you want, you can use `SUBSTR` combined with `RANK` to get a particular character's value).  You can also put it to $HEX. to see the entire string.  Here I use RANK to show you the reason it's sorted the way it is.

```
proc format lib=work;
    value $productfmt
           "Boot"           = "<"
           "Men's Casual"   = "!"
           "Women's Casual" = "A" 
           "Men's Dress"    = "B" 
           "Women's Dress"  = "5"
           "Sandal"         = "6" 
           "Slipper"        = "7" 
           "Sport Shoe"     = "08" ;    
QUIT;

data work.newshoes;
 set sashelp.shoes; /* the original data set */
     NEWPRODUCT = PRODUCT;

    format NEWPRODUCT $productfmt.;
    ascii = rank(put(newproduct,$productfmt.));
run;

proc freq data=work.newshoes order=formatted;
    table NEWPRODUCT*ascii/list;
run;
```